# Non-uniform density of observations

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

I would like to build a regression model to predict an outcome variable, y. Let ymin, ymax be the smallest and largest observed values of y in the dataset. Let ymean be the mean observed value. The dataset has a non-uniform frequency distribution, with very few data points near the limits, ymin and ymax and a large number of datapoints near ymean. Naively, I expect that the model error near the limits will be more than the model error near the mean. Are there techniques to reduce the error near the limits? Isn't this a very commonly occuring problem?

Comment: Could you be more specific about your model?  There are plenty of models for data like this where the error near the limits will be extremely *small* rather than large.

Comment: Is it possible to compare linear regression, tree based methods (RF, Boosted Trees) and neural network based models vis-a-vis the issue described? I would like to gain intuition behind how a method can be accurate in ranges where the data is sparse.

Comment: I cannot understand what you are trying to ask.  In most datasets, data are sparsest near the extremes, so your question sounds somewhat like a complicated way of asking "how do I do regression?"

Comment: You might try weighted regression, with weights calculated by y-value distance from ymean somehow. For example, data points at ymean would have a weight of 1.0, and weights far from ymean would have a larger weight. I'm suspicious that while this might appear to solve the immediate problem, it would also introduce other problems  - however, it might be worth a try.

Comment: It's not clear whether you're describing the conditional distribution or the marginal distribution (and it matters!). Could you describe your variables and show us what you're looking at?